# ajax conditional if statements loading pages

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently working on a site which requires ajax to load the inner pages, however certain groups of pages require a background change as well as a container width change.

Is there anyway I could use conditional if statements to change the class / css on certain elements? If so how would I go about it?

Sorry forgot to say, conditional on the page url.

So if url = innerpage.html change class on

All this works to a fashion:

```
$('nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    hideView()
    $('#ajax-page').hide('fast', loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#container').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function hideView() {
        $('#container').find('.view').fadeOut('fast');
    }
    function loadContent() {
        $('#ajax-page').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#ajax-page').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Yes, but conditional on what?  The page url?

Comment: Can we see an example of your code?

Comment: I think your question should be more specific.  I would say... OF COURSE you can use conditional if statements to change stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` functions to add and remove classes from elements.  Also use jQuery `.css('attr','value')` to change css on that element.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of background and width is very limited, you could prepare classes in your CSS and pass the class needed via Ajax.

If however you have lots of variations, and want to do some preloading/animating, then you should pass from the server all the relevant raw data (background, width, content) as a Json object via the data argument of the success response, then test them for relevance and apply/not apply them with .html() and .attr().